# Android ~ ListViewAdapter Struggles

Tags: java, android, http, listview, gridview

I'm really struggling with the `ListView` and the `Adapter`. I want to get a string from a `HttpGet` and present that as a item in the `Listview`. Before you ask, I've tried my hardest and I simply can't do it.

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: You should show what have you done so that someone can improvise and make it working...

Comment: I don't have any, all the code would be waste of your time, as it completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Store all string into `ArrayList<String>` and pass them to adapter, and use custom list ite, with `TextView` for showing string.

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_item, result );
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is the example : [Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)